# Create a binary matrix from 2 dataframe columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix

I need to create a binary matrix

Example Data in a pandas DataFrame

```
ID P
2  1
1  2
3  2
1  3
1  4
2  5
3  5
```

Using

```
A = pd.DataFrame(index=df.ID.values, columns=df.P.values, 
                       data=(df.P.values == df.P.values[:,None]).astype(int))
```

My current output

[image: Current Output]

Which is correct in terms of where the '1's' hit, but I just want to have the column / row numbers consolidated and the row numbers in order as in:

```
index 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1     0 1 1 1 0 1 0
2     1 0 0 0 1 0 1
3     0 1 0 1 1 1 0
```

If that's not clear, feel free to question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`get_dumies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) with `max`:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('ID')['P'].astype(str)).max(level=0).sort_index()
print (df)
    1  2  3  4  5
ID               
1   0  1  1  1  0
2   1  0  0  0  1
3   0  1  0  0  1
```

Comment: Worked a treat! Thanks @jezrael

Answer (score 0):

You could try [pivot_table function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html)

```
df["value"]=1
pd.pivot_table(df, values="value", index=["ID"], columns="P", fill_value=0)
```